# SELECT and COUNT greater values and lesser values in one query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have some values in a table and I want to count all od them, all greater than given date and lesser than given date. Let's say I have table like this

```
id   | date
-----------------
1    | 2015-06-30
2    | 2015-06-28
3    | 2015-06-25
4    | 2015-06-23
5    | 2015-06-20
6    | 2015-06-08
7    | 2015-06-10
```

and I want to have that result is the date is 2015-06-15

```
all | greater | lesser
----------------------
7   | 5       | 2
```

Comment: That seems quite straightforward, so what's the problem?

Comment: I can count all records OR greater records OR lesser records, but I can't find a way to do it all without a nested selects

Comment: e.g. SUM(date > 'my_date')

Comment: can be without id =1, just a habit

Comment: might want to quit that habit!

Comment: quite interesting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not much aware of MYSQL, but in oracle it will serve the purpose.

```
SELECT   SUM (COUNT (*)) AS all_count, COUNT (date_1) AS greater,
         SUM (COUNT (*)) - COUNT (date_1) AS lesser
    FROM t x JOIN t y USING (date_1)
GROUP BY date_1
  HAVING (date_1 > TO_DATE ('20150615', 'YYYYMMDD'))
```

hope it will help you and you can implement same thing in MYSQL.

All the Best :)